# Is it possible to create a signed email with an opaque signature using MimeKit?

Tags: c#, smime, mimekit

Basically as the questions states.

I have written a program to sign an email using an X509Certificate2 installed on a users machine.  This is done with MimeKit, which makes it very easy (as shown).

```
var signer = new CmsSigner(certificate, key);
signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha1;

message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, messageContent);
```

I've just been asked if it is possible to create this signed email using an 'opaque' signature instead of a detached signature.  I believe there is an option in OpenSSL that can do this(??).

Anyway, I've been unable to find any mention of an 'opaque' option in relation to MimeKit.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is also possible. With regards to S/MIME, when people refer to an opaque signature, what they mean is that they want a signature in the application/pkcs7-mime format. Here's how you would go about creating that:

```
var signer = new CmsSigner(certificate, key);
signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha1;

message.Body = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Sign(ctx, signer, messageContent);
```

Hope that helps!

Note:

> In late 2013, Microsoft announced that they would be retiring their
>   use of SHA-1 in their products by 2016 with the assumption that its
>   days as an unbroken digest algorithm were numbered. It is speculated
>   that the SHA-1 digest algorithm will be vulnerable to collisions, and
>   thus no longer considered secure, by 2018.
>
> Microsoft and other vendors plan to move to the SHA-2 suite of digest
>   algorithms which includes the following 4 variants: SHA-224, SHA-256,
>   SHA-384, and SHA-512.

Comment: Thanks for the tip RE SHA-1.  I'll switch over to one of the variants.

Comment: No problem! I should probably update the samples to use one of the newer variants as well, to lead by good example :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SignEmail( MimeMessage m, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate, Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter key, MailboxAddress sender, MimeEntity content)
    {
        var signer = new MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner( certificate, key );
        signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha1;

        m.Body = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Sign( sender, signer.DigestAlgorithm, content );
    }
```